# How do I display candle data from "1 Hour" timeframe into "4 Hour" timeframe?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Consider this fictive example which illustrates the problem:

At "1 Hour Timeframe" we are looking at the last 3 candle's "High":

- c[0] High = 1000 (8 AM candle)
- c[1] High = 1001 (7 AM candle)
- c[2] High = 1002 (6 AM candle)

I want to have these 3 candles (c[0]-[1]-[2] from 1 Hour Timeframe)...displayed at the 4 Hour Timeframe...on the most current candle (i.e. the c[0])

**To summarize: I'm interested in displaying data from a lower timeframe (e.g. 1H)..to a higher timeframe I'm on (e.g. 4H)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the newly introduced `request.security_lower_tf()` function for that.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)


// If the current chart timeframe is set to 240 minutes, then the `arrHigh` array will contain four 'high' values from the 60 minute timeframe for each bar.
arrHigh  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high)

if bar_index == last_bar_index - 1
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(arrClose))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!! I wasn't aware of the v5 built-in function. Could I ask a further question? How do I access/store these values  (from 1H timeframe)..." individually"? (i.e. I'm going to add them in an array)

Comment: Well, it returns an array. Just access its elements using the `array.get()` function.